# Getting FileNotFoundException (Permission denied) when trying to read metadata from a picture

Tags: java, android, metadata-extractor

I am accessing pictures of the device's gallery via my app, when the picture is accessed the metadata of the picture will be read and stored in `metadata`. The problem I'm facing is that whenever the program tries to read the metadata I'm getting the following error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Snapchat/Snapchat-1185425082.jpg (Permission denied)`.

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){

        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        File picturesfile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        picturesfile.setReadable(true);
        picturesfile.setExecutable(true);




        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        try {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);


            Log.d("Picture Path", path);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Path Error", e.toString());
        }

        File jpegFile = new File(path);
        jpegFile.setReadable(true);
        jpegFile.setExecutable(true);

        try {
             metadata =  ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);
            for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
                for (Tag hoi : directory.getTags()) {
                    Log.d("tags ", hoi.toString());
                }
            }


        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tactically, it would appear that you do not have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, which [you need to request in the manifest and at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Beyond that:

- There is no requirement for your `query()` to return a `DATA` column
- There is no requirement that the `DATA` column have a value
- There is no requirement that the `DATA` column have a filesystem path
- There is no requirement that the filesystem path in the `DATA` column be a file that you can access, even with `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

In particular, it is guaranteed that your code will fail on Android Q, and it is very likely to fail for lots of users on lots of other devices as well.

Use the `Uri` (`imageUri`) with `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` (or perhaps a `FileDescriptor`) to pass to your library.